# C++: Can I change a vector type?

Tags: c++, vector

Let's assume I have the following code:

```cpp
typedef struct foo{
    int x;
}foo;

typedef struct bar{
    int y
}bar;

struct foobar{
    std::vector<foo> foo1;
    std::vector<bar> bar1;
};
```

Is there any way to change `std::vector<bar> bar1;` into `std::vector<foo> bar1;` and erase any data inside?

And if so, could this be done in a function? Something like this?

```cpp
replaceBar(&myOwnStruct);
```

I am not too great with vectors, so an explanaitaion to why this is/isn't possible would be nice.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a theoretical question (no, you can't change a type), or do you have a use case for it?

Comment: What's the logic by which you would expect this to be possible? Is there supposed to be some kind of relationship, in the example, between the foo and bar types? What *problem do you hope to solve* by doing this?

Comment: Write a wrapper around `std::vector<std::any>`?

Comment: You can "convert" the contents of a `std::vector<foo>` into a `std::vector<bar>` if there is a meaningful conversion between `foo` and `bar`. If the conversion is implicit, you can simply copy the range. Or you can use `std::transform`. But this requires creating a new vector having the other type and transferring the elements. In C++, an object has a type and it is impossible for an object's type to change during the course of its lifetime.

Comment: `typedef struct X {...} X;` is not necessary in C++.  Just use `struct X {...};`.

Comment: FYI: `typedef struct` isn’t required in C++. You can just say `struct foo { /* … */ };` and then declare variables of type `foo`.

Comment: I was thinking that this could be used in something like a game engine, where foo and bar could be objects in a 3D world. My question is, can the user add a extra variable onto bar, eg its mass via replacing bar's type. Like I said, I'm not great with vectors so overall this might seem like a dumb idea but I'm just curious if something like this could be possible.

Comment: It looks like you might want to learn about *object oriented programming*.

Comment: @deezNuts In a game engine context where you have many "types" of objects, most likely it won't be represented as a C++ type, as one only type (eg `Entity`) can represent any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to "change" a variable's type (which is not really possible in C++) from one type to another is to use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to indicate the possible types it is allowed to hold (or, use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) to hold all types), eg:

```cpp
std::variant<std::vector<bar>, std::vector<foo>> bar1;
```

You could then have `bar1` hold a `std::vector<bar>` initially, and then at a later time reassign it to hold a `std::vector<foo>` instead.

```
struct foo{
    int x;
};

struct bar{
    int y;
};

struct foobar{
    std::vector<foo> foo1;
    std::variant<std::vector<bar>, std::vector<foo>> bar1;
};

void replaceBar(foobar *fb) {
    fb->bar1 = std::vector<foo>{};
}

foobar myOwnStruct;
foobar.bar1 = std::vector<bar>{};
replaceBar(&myOwnStruct);
```

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are layout-compatible types, which requires the same alignment requirements. We could probably `std::bitcast` `vector<foo>` to `vector<bar>` (obviously I'm not sure about that or whether we'd still run afoul of UB, otherwise I'd post an answer)

Comment: @AndyG `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` are separate unrelated types when `A != B`. So casting one such vector into another is always UB, even if their elements are layout-compatible

Answer (score 1):

Possibility 1: If foo and bar can have a common base class.
You could then have the vector be of pointers to the base class. You can then re-point the pointer to a different object. But it will reallocate memory. Not exactly what you wanted.
Possibility 2: You could declare a union. But note that the vector's memory is on heap so it doesnt really achieve your objective and you'll have to be careful about destructors. If it were plain object arrays with fixed sizes, you could do it.
Possiblity 3: This may work for you in games. Instead of storing a vector directly, store a flatbuffers serialized block of bytes. You can rewrite a different thing into those bytes. You'll need another variable in the struct to say what's in those bytes. Maybe this option is too far out there for you !